# Typescript/Angular: Updating a Getter/Setter type casting in an extended class/component

Tags: angular, typescript, types, enums, casting

I've attempted to dumb this down, so the use case for wanting this is less clear but the problem remains.

Problem: Being unable to expand/update/declare enums or types within a class

Goal: Rather than rewriting the getter/setter in extended class's with the new type whenever 'ValidState' deviates from the default in the base class, is there a way to do this so the getter/setters would be aware of the new type?

Example Base Class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export enum DefaultValidStates {
  LOADING = 'LOADING',
  READY = 'READY',
}

type ValidState = DefaultValidStates;
// Is there a way for this to be within a class so it can be updated in extended classes and still trigger type checks

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  template: '<p>BaseComponent status = {{status}}</p>',
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit{
  private _status: ValidState | undefined;

  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.status = DefaultValidStates.LOADING;
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = DefaultValidStates.READY;
    }, 3000)
  }

  get status(): ValidState | undefined {
    return this._status;
  }

  set status(status: ValidState | undefined) {
    this._status = status;
  }
}
```

Example Extended Class

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BaseComponent, DefaultValidStates} from "../base/base.component";

enum OtherValidStates {
  FATAL_ERROR = 'FATAL_ERROR',
}

type ValidState = DefaultValidStates | OtherValidStates;
// Is there someway to pass/use this new type so the base class knows of it

@Component({
  selector: 'app-other',
  template: '<p>OtherComponent status = {{status}}</p>',
})
export class OtherComponent extends BaseComponent{
  
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.status = DefaultValidStates.LOADING;
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = OtherValidStates.FATAL_ERROR;
      // Because ValidState is what is set in BaseComponent this won't compile
      // Type 'OtherValidStates' is not assignable to type 'DefaultValidStates | undefined'.
    }, 3000)
  }
}
```

Cheers,

Edits: Attempting to clarify issue.

Comment: The `validState` type is not overwritten by the `Extend` keyword because it's not part of the class to begin with.

Comment: @Kokodoko Thanks for the reply, sorry I wasn't clearer, I'm away of the issue, I was trying to show the goal, that being updating the type in the extended class

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution

Base Class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export enum DefaultValidStates {
  LOADING = 'LOADING',
  READY = 'READY',
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  template: '<p>BaseComponent status = {{status}}</p>',
})
export class BaseComponent<States = undefined, ValidStates = States> implements OnInit{

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.status = DefaultValidStates.LOADING;
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = DefaultValidStates.READY;
    }, 3000)
  }

  private _status: DefaultValidStates | ValidStates | undefined;

  get status(): DefaultValidStates | ValidStates | undefined {
    return this._status;
  }

  set status(status: DefaultValidStates | ValidStates | undefined) {
    this._status = status;
  }
}
```

Extended

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BaseComponent, DefaultValidStates} from "../base/base.component";

enum OtherValidStates {
  FATAL_ERROR = 'FATAL_ERROR',
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-other',
  template: '<p>OtherComponent status = {{status}}</p>',
})
export class OtherComponent extends BaseComponent<OtherValidStates> implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.status = DefaultValidStates.LOADING;
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = OtherValidStates.FATAL_ERROR;
    }, 3000)
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).